# Using hi-lock-mode to change foreground colour of particular elisp comments

Tags: faces

The following code uses `hi-lock-mode` to highlight certain comments beginning with `;; [`.  This changes the background  colour.  Instead of changing the background colour, I would like to change the foreground colour only.  Would need to set up a face for it, but do not have much experience working with them.

```
(defun hl-regexp ()
  (interactive)
  (highlight-regexp "^;; \\[.*$"))

(defun hl-comment-heading ()
  "TODO."
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.el\\'" . hi-lock-mode))
  (add-hook 'hi-lock-mode-hook 'hl-regexp))
```

Comment: Pose a specific question about a specific problem you have defining a face or understanding how to define a face. Don't just say "I don't understand how to define a face." Show the code you tried, and ask about it.

Comment: The specific question is that whilst I can get to highlight a pattern with `regexp` using `hi-lock-mode`, doing `(highlight-regexp "^;; \\[.*$")` implements a predefined face than changes the background colour.  But I want to only change the foreground colour.

Comment: Customize the face to be as you like.

Comment: Have made  my own face.